# macOS - back up to a shared hard drive with Time Machine on Mac

Tags: macos, time-machine

I want to use one hard drive for multiple computer backups.  You can do this with macOS Server but it's no longer supported in newer OS.  I believe Time Capsule was able to do this too (attach an external drive to backup multiple computers.)

So found the article [Back up to a shared folder with Time Machine on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl31533145/mac)

I was successful in configuring it but then I got this error.

"You do not have the necessary read, write, and append privileges on the selected network backup disk.  Please connect as a different user or contact your network administrator"

Looking at the older macOS server setup and the new Time Machine drive setup the permissions are definitely different.

Does anyone know or has successfully done this? I don't want to share a folder on the internal drive since the external drive is much larger.

Comment: By external drive do you mean a drive you access by SMB (external drive usually means attached by thunderbolt or USB) . If so what are the user credentials you use to connect?

Comment: @mmmmmm - there is a physical external drive (USB) that is shared through SMB on the network.